# apache Ignite nunit tests failed to run on build agent: Failed to load jvm.dll

Tags: c#, ignite

I have integration tests (NUnit) which hosts ignite cluster in background using Ignition.StartFromApplicationConfiguration() method. When I run tests on my local machine everything is ok, but on build agent tests fails with the following error:

```
Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException : Failed to load jvm.dll:
[option=JAVA_HOME, path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\server\jvm.dll, error=DLL could not be loaded (126: ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND). This can be caused by missing dependencies. ]
[option=JAVA_HOME, path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\client\jvm.dll, error=DLL could not be loaded (126: ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND). This can be caused by missing dependencies. ]
[option=JAVA_HOME, path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll, error=DLL could not be loaded (126: ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND). This can be caused by missing dependencies. ]
[option=JAVA_HOME, path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll, error=DLL could not be loaded (126: ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND). This can be caused by missing dependencies. ]
[option=JAVA_HOME, path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\jre\bin\default\jvm.dll, error=DLL could not be loaded (126: ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND). This can be caused by missing dependencies. ]
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.JvmDll.Load(String configJvmDllPath, ILogger log)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Ignition.Start(IgniteConfiguration cfg)
```

I downloaded "apache-ignite-2.11.0-bin.zip" on build agent machine. I succesfully launch Apache Ignite from script "apache-ignite-2.11.0-bin\bin\ignite.bat" without errors, but when I try to launch it via dotnet bootstrapper "apache-ignite-2.11.0-bin\platforms\dotnet\bin\Apache.Ignite.exe" I get the same error.
My local machine is Windows 10 x64, build agent has Windows Server 2019 x64. Java 14.0.1 is installed on both machines, jvm.dll exists in folder 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\server'. JAVA_HOME variable is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1" on both machines, IGNITE_HOME variable is not set on machines.

PS. Apache.Ignite.exe is not launched for latest 2.12.0 release on both machines with the following error:

```
ERROR: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for igniteConfiguration: Type 'Apache.Ignite.Core.IgniteConfigurationSection' does not inherit from 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler'. (D:\temp\apache-ignite-2.12.0-bin\platforms\dotnet\bin\net461\Apache.Ignite.exe.Config line 23) ---> System.TypeLoadException: Type 'Apache.Ignite.Core.IgniteConfigurationSection' does not inherit from 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler'.
   at System.Configuration.TypeUtil.VerifyAssignableType(Type baseType, Type type, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.CreateSectionFactory(FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at Apache.Ignite.Config.Configurator.ReadConfigurationSection(Tuple`2[] args)
   at Apache.Ignite.Config.Configurator.GetConfiguration(Tuple`2[] args)
   at Apache.Ignite.IgniteRunner.Main(String[] args)
```